# Sorbet LSP sublime text read typed: false

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, language-server-protocol, sorbet

So I'm using LSP and Sorbet with Sublime Text 3. I have an issue in my RSpec files that have `typed: false` in them. The engine spits out tons of type errors:

```
5:3   error   Method `it` does not exist on `T.class_of(<root>)` ​unknown-source:
6:5   error   Method `expect` does not exist on `T.class_of(<root>)` (fix available) ​unknown-source:
7:11  error   Method `be_a` does not exist on `T.class_of(<root>)` ​unknown-source:
```

It's inside a `RSpec.describe` block. Is there a way to make LSP not to run on typed: false or even better, is there a way to let Sorbet know these methods exists?

I use:

```
sorbet
sorbet-runtime
```

I've tried adding `rspec-sorbet` aswell but didn't help.

Note: I've also run `srb rbi gems`.